# Laravel add column with a default value depending on a second column

Tags: sql, laravel, sqlite

I have a User table I want to view each User by navigating `/users/{slug}`. e.g. for a User named `John Doe` the route would look like this `/users/john-doe`. Currently I am using the id to view a User (`/users/1`). To achieve this I could just iterate over all Users create the slug and check if the given slug is the same. But this wouldn't be that efficient and if I have hundreds of Users this would take time. I thought about adding a new column.

```php
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('slug')->after('name');
});
```

The problem is this won't work because the column needs a default value and the "default" value depends on the value of `name`.

I could also just add the column in the `Schema::create(...)` function and run `php artisan migrate:refresh`. But like this I would lose all other Users.

Does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this exact same thing; a `slug` is generated from the `name` (or `title`, etc.) column, but I don't do this in the database.

When you're creating a `User` model instance, set the `slug`, something like:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
  $request->merge(['slug' => Str::slug($request->input('name'))]);

  // Validate `$request`

  User::create($request);

  // OR

  $user = new User();
  $user->name = $request->input('name');
  $user->slug = Str::slug($user->name);
  $user->save();
}
```

Additionally, if using a `FormRequest`, this can be done like:

```php
public function store(MyFormRequest $request) { 
  User::create($request);
}
```

Inside of `MyFormRequest.php`:

```php
class MyFormRequest extends FormRequest {
  protected function prepareForValidation() {
    $this->merge(['slug' => Str::slug($this->name)]);
  }

  public function rules() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In your case, since you've got a bunch of existing Users, you'd need to run something like:

```php
foreach(User::all() as $user) {
  $user->update(['slug' => Str::slug($user->name)]);
}
```

After running the migration to "backfill" your slugs.

Sidenote, be careful with relying on names for slugs; people do not have unique names, so you might end up with 2 "John Doe" slugs, which will require some custom logic to differentiate them.

Answer (score 1):

You can literally just add a [resolveRouteBinding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic) function to your users model to resolve the model.

```php
/**
 * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @param  string|null  $field
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
*/
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
{
    if ($field != null) {
        return parent::resolveRouteBinding($value, $field);
    } elseif (is_numeric($value)) {
        return parent::resolveRouteBinding($value, 'id');
    } else {
        return parent::resolveRouteBinding($value, 'slug');
    }
}
```

With this function Laravel will auto resolve your model by your slug or by an id if the given value is numeric.

For generating the slug, I would go with an [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#observers) that will set the slug on `creating`. You should be able to to easily fill it before saving the model to the database. To keep the slug up to date you can just use the `updating` event of the observer.

```php
/**
 * Handle the User "creating" event.
 */
public function creating(User $user): void
{
    $user->slug = Str::slug($user->name);
}
```

For the first migration I would go with a default value or allow it to be nullable. You can change that in another migration when you have initially set the slug for each user.

BR,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

In SQL in general, you can't really set a "dynamic" default value (depending on another column). However, what you can do is to set the column `nullable`, then compute its value programmatically for the existing rows, and finally changing the column to be `not null`.

Example:

```php
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('slug')->nullable()->after('name');
});

// Compute slug values

Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('slug')->nullable(false)->change();
});
```

Comment: For this migration, if you omit `nullable()`, the `slug` column will be created with `ALLOW_NULL: FALSE`, meaning any new rows cannot have `slug` as `null`, but existing rows will not be checked, and can exist with `null` (or `empty`). Once they do the data migration (i.e. compute the slug values), the rows will all have a string value for `slug`, so the 2nd `->nullable(false)->change()` is not necessary 

Comment: No problem! Sidenote, I'm not sure if this behaviour is the same across DB engines (MySQL, Postgres, sqlite, etc.) so definitely keep this answer, as they _might_ actually have to do this. Cheers 